# How to check whether user rated our application in Google Play or NOT?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm wonder if there is a way to check whether current user/device rated our application in Google Play using Android Java Code or any other trick (i.e. web service OR API)..

One more thing, Can I rate our app within the application code?

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot do this. And this is a good thing too -- otherwise you will be able to influence rating by giving people who rated it rewards and such.